# Oracle problems with DATEs

Tags: oracle, date

iam confused. Iam trying to read an Value from an oracle table, format: timestamp(6).

In my PHP Scripts im setting the Dateformat with:

```
$db->query('ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = "DD-MM-RR"');
```

On 2 Machines im recieving this string as value (wich is correct for me):
 **["TIME_INSERT"] => string(24) "05.10.07 14:20:05,000000"**

On one linux machines where the same script is running, it returns:
 **["TIME_INSERT"] => string(28) "05-OCT-07 02.20.05.000000 PM"**

any ideas how to change this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should set the session parameter `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` or `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` to display timestamp data as you want:

```
SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
----------------------------------------------------
12/10/09 12:52:41,462532 +02:00

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'dd.mm.rr hh24:mi:ss,ff5';

Session altered

SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12.10.09 12:56:36,14023
```

Comment: I generally use a TO_CHAR() in the SQL or bind to a JDBC data type.  Seems better than setting a session parameter.

Comment: ...and use TO_DATE(...) the other way to insert values in the format of your choice.

Comment: @WW and awe: I agree, I always advocate the use of explicit date conversion.

Comment: sorry still the same result after setting the timestamp format (;